# Only the last value is added to the array

Tags: php

Only the last value is added to the loop. I could not find where I was making mistakes. Is there anything you can do to help?

```
<?php

$pdo = $this->getEntityManager()->getPDO();
$users = $this->getUserList();

foreach ($users as $user) {
    $sql = "SELECT
                COUNT( assigned_status ) AS 'Adet',
                SUM( CASE WHEN m.assigned_status = 'Olumlu' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS Olumlu,
                SUM( CASE WHEN m.assigned_status = 'Olumsuz' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS Olumsuz,
                SUM( CASE WHEN m.assigned_status = 'Satış' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS Satış,
                SUM( CASE WHEN m.assigned_status = 'Ertelenme' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS Ertelenme 
            FROM
                meeting m 
            WHERE
                assigned_user_id = '" . $user['user_id'] . "'";

    $sth = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute();
    $data = $sth->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $resultData = array();
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        $resultData['Olumlu'] = array(
            $user['full_name'] => array('Fly Team' => intval($row['Olumlu']))
        );
    }
}

return $resultData;
```

Comment: change `$resultData['Olumlu']` to `$resultData[]['Olumlu']`

Comment: Read about [PHP arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). The answer is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mistake here

```
foreach ($data as $row) {
        $resultData['Olumlu'] = array(
            $user['full_name'] => array('Fly Team' => intval($row['Olumlu']))
        );
    }
```

change to

```
foreach ($data as $row) {
        $resultData['Olumlu'][] = array(
            $user['full_name'] => array('Fly Team' => intval($row['Olumlu']))
        );
    }
```

Comment: What exactly did you change? A good answer describes the issue, what the problem was, and outlines why the changes you made was necessary. I can see what you did, but others might not. *Always* explain your answers.

Comment: issue was here will not put $resultData['Olumlu'] here array $resultData['Olumlu'][] this. That's why only added last value in array

Answer (score 0):

you must try like this

```
 $resultData = array();
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        $resultData[]['Olumlu'] = array(
            $user['full_name'] => array('Fly Team' => intval($row['Olumlu']))
        );
    }
```

This will work for you

Comment: Why should anyone *try this*? Why would this work? Always explain your answers.